# Spring Boot 2.4 changes

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Within next few months 6th edition of Spring in Action is going to be published.
It is said, it will not contain 3 chapters from 5th edition i.e. Circut Breaker,
Eureka Service-Client Discovery, Eureka Server-Client Configuration.
Instead of this, it will include changes made in Spring Boot 2.4. I have
alread heard that Circut Breaker (Hystrix) is outdated, but I wonder what about
rest, especially omitted chapters ? I noticed that I can not choose ribbon in newest(2.4.3) Spring Boot version, zipkin also differs from earlies ones. What is alternative for ribbon in newest version?

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Cloud project is moving to their own solutions.

Ribbon is replaced by the Spring Cloud Load Balancer, Hysterix by the Spring Cloud Circuit Breaker, Zuul by the Spring Cloud Gateway.

This is a good read, including examples, about this topic: https://piotrminkowski.com/2020/05/01/a-new-era-of-spring-cloud/